# Hiding certain channel of an image with C#

Tags: c#, image, rgb, color-channel

i have an image processing application that is able to getpixel, anyone know how can i hide or show the RGB channel of my image? For example when i click a button call "RED" it will hide red channel and show only blue and green. i m using C# btw
thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) library. Use the `AForge.Imaging.Filters.ChannelFiltering` filter.

Comment: Hey thx alot for ur help .. still working on it thou but i think it should work (:

Comment: hi any idea how i can UNapply the filter ? as when i click on the red filter and then click on the blue filter, the blue will overlay with the red. thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a `blank` image (1 channel) of the same size as the original image.  Then, when handling a button press for `RED`, do the following:

- *split* your original image into `R`, `G` and `B`
- *compose* a new image using `blank`, `G`, `B` (in that order, as the order of channels is important).  This leaves out the red channel
- *display* the composed image

Handle button presses for `BLUE` and `GREEN` in similar fashion.

*split*, *compose* and *display* methods are common in imaging libraries.  Their exact names may differ depending on the library you are using, but their overall functionality should generally be the same.  By the way, what library are you using?  You didn't mention it in your question.

If you're not using any library to achieve what you're doing, you will have to write your own *split* and *compose* functions (or something along those lines).   You would have to say more about the data structures you are using to get help in that direction.